# Taking a screenshot from a pyqt script by selecting the area

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

How do I take a screenshot in PyQt?

I found QRubberBand Class, however I am unsure of how to do that in PyQt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QtGui.QPixmap` will do the trick for you, use it's `grabWindow()` method like this:

```
pixmap = QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId())
```

This will tak a screenshot of current desktop.
Now you can use `QRubberband` to select a specific area on the pixmap and use `QPixmap.copy()` to copy that selected area as another pixmap and finally use `QPixmap.save()` to save the selected area.

For more information look through Qt documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/qtmodules.html)